# Fetching data from Nodejs using React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Using this I am fetching code from the Nodejs Backend

But the problem is when I click on submit button in a form it changes the variables in the state are changed, but the call has already been made with the default values in the state.
So I want the fetch function to be called only when the submit button is clicked with the changed state values.

how do I do it?

My code==

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/customers/'+this.state.category1+'/'+this.state.zip1+'/'+this.state.age1+'/'+'/'+this.state.gender1)
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(customers => this.setState({customers}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', customers)));
}
```

> Useless code if you want next

```
<form onSubmit={this.performTask.bind(this)}>

    <select value={this.state.category1} onChange={this.changeCategory1.bind(this)} >
        <option >Auto</option><option>Life</option>
    </select>
    <br/>

    <input type="text" onChange={this.changeZipCode.bind(this)}/>
    </div>
        <div>
            <select name="gender" className="form-control form-control-lg">
                <option>Male</option>
                <option>Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label >Age</label>
        <br/>

        <input type="text" ref="ageref1" onChange={this.changeAge1.bind(this)} placeholder="35" className="ap-input"  role="combobox"  />

        <br/>
        <button type="submit" className="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

This function is redirecting the page so the state variables I think get lost . I dont get anything in the console

```
performTask(event){

        browserHistory.push("/data");
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.state.zip1);
        console.log(this.state.age1);
        console.log("asd");
        fetch('/api/customers/'+this.state.category1+'/'+this.state.zip1+'/'+this.state.age1+'/'+'/'+this.state.gender1)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(customers => this.setState({customers}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', customers)));
        //event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you binding the methods in the jsx? It would help to see your full code, because I think you are messing up the context being bound to the methods.

Comment: Full code is here https://jsfiddle.net/0r2nxegv/

Comment: @asd Did any of the responses help you? if you need more information we are here to help!

Answer (score 0):

WHY(TH) you're fetching in `componentDidMmount` if you need it done on submit ? Just move this code into `this.performTask`, done.

Binding in render is minor error, bind methods in constructor or use ES6 syntax.

Comment: I am a begginner ,can you please tell me what do you mean by binding in constructor what Do i need to do?

Comment: @asd any method that accesses `this` and is used in a callback needs to be bound to the class so that the version of `this` it is using is consistent. You can do that in the constructor method: `this.someCustomFunction = this.someCustomFunction.bind(this)`. It's an unfortunate issue with JS classes. Learn more: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a response if you remove browserHistory.push("/data")? Try adding a catch statement to your promise and changing the route in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either bind functions in the constructor or alternatively use arrow functions for your functions to be called properly. Also, some of these functions that receive an event will require to `preventDefault()` so you prevent the default behaviour to do whatever you need when the button is clicked.

```
performTask(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent first
    browserHistory.push("/data");
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.state.zip1);
    console.log(this.state.age1);
    console.log("asd");
    fetch('/api/customers/' + this.state.category1 + '/' + this.state.zip1 + '/' + this.state.age1 + '/' + '/' + this.state.gender1)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(customers => this.setState({customers}, () => console.log('Customers fetched...', customers)));
}

changeZipCode(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent first
    this.setState({zip1: event.target.value});
}
changeAge1(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent first
    this.setState({age1: event.target.value});
}

changeCategory1(event) {
    // No need to prevent default
    this.setState({category1: event.target.value});
}
```

**Bind functions in constructor**

1) Bind

```
this.functionName.bind(this);
```

2) Call like this:

```
this.functionName
```

In your case:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        customers: [],
        category1: "Auto",
        gender1: "Male",
        zip1: 90293,
        age1: 22
    };

    // Bind functions
    this.performTask = this.performTask.bind(this);
    this.changeCategory1 = this.changeCategory1.bind(this);
    this.changeZipCode = this.changeZipCode.bind(this);
    this.changeAge1 = this.changeAge1.bind(this);
}
```

And use them like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.performTask}>

<select value={this.state.category1}  onChange={this.changeCategory1} className="form-control form-control-lg">

<input type="text" ref="zipcoderef1" onChange={this.changeZipCode} placeholder="110045" className="ap-input"  role="combobox" dir="auto" />

<input type="text" ref="ageref1" onChange={this.changeAge1} placeholder="35" className="ap-input"  role="combobox"  />
```

**Arrow functions**

1) Don't bind, keep constructor the same

2) Call like this:

```
(params) => this.functionName(params)
```

In your case:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        customers: [],
        category1: "Auto",
        gender1: "Male",
        zip1: 90293,
        age1: 22
    };
}
```

Use arrow functions when calling the functions:

```
<form onSubmit={(e)=>this.performTask(e)}>

<select value={this.state.category1}  onChange={(e)=>this.changeCategory1(e)} className="form-control form-control-lg">

<input type="text" ref="zipcoderef1" onChange={(e)=>this.changeZipCode(e)} placeholder="110045" className="ap-input"  role="combobox" dir="auto" />

<input type="text" ref="ageref1" onChange={(e)=>this.changeAge1(e)} placeholder="35" className="ap-input"  role="combobox"  />
```

The `e` in the arrow functions is the parameter that 
 those functions will receive, in this case `e` will always be the `event` for these type of components, in other components this differ.